# Why does mysqli still escape quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using prepare statements in mysqli and if I put a `"` into one of my params values then it escapes it and adds a backslash before it. I though mysqli didn't have to do this?? Thanks. Example:

```
$comment = $members->prepare("insert into comments(comment) values(?)");
$comment->bind_param('s', $_POST['comment']);
$comment->execute();
```

puts \"\" into the database assuming that the comment field is equal to ""

Comment: Are you on an ancient PHP with automagic quotes?

Comment: lol php version is 5.2.13 and hoster is ehosting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server may have magic quotes on.  Check it out here http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php  It's happened to me before, very annoying.

quick check to see

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        echo "Magic quotes are enabled";
    else
        echo "Magic quotes are disabled";
```

Comment: Yea thanks they are on :(, any way i can turn them off ? cheers

Comment: i guess i could use stripslashes() but then that would remove all the users aswell but its better than having them put there

Comment: Most hosting accounts allow you to create a php.ini file in the root of your hosting account. Just have a single line with `magic_quotes_gpc = Off`. If not you can try the following line in an .htaccess file - `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off`

Comment: haha i tried but it doesnt work ( i think its because im on windows hosting which doesnt seem to let you do anything )